# Modular quadratic equation help

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

our professor gave us one "equation to think at" (as he says). I tried to "think at" since friday but I don't know how to handle it properly and (if any) if there are solutions of families of solutions.
The equation seems pretty simple:

Given $P,N,a$ rigorously integer numbers greater than $0$.

We have that

$(X^2+a)$ Mod N = $P$

and

$(Y^2+a)$ Mod N = $P$

How can we find $X$ and $Y$ that yield to the solution ?  Of course $X$ and $Y$ must be different ($X\neq Y$)

I make an example :

a= 203
N = 7979

Then we have $X=2944$ and $Y=6378$ that give the same $P=2145$.

But then do exist other $X$ and $Y$ that give the same $P=2145$ result ?

Or, in other manner, if I say for example that $P=2001$, how can we find the solutions ($X$ and $Y$)?

Thanks

Comment: This is not clear.  What is a "rigorously integer number"?  What is the point of having $a$ and $p$?  Aren't you just asking to solve $x^2\equiv (p-a)\pmod n$ which has at least two solutions if it has any at all (for most $n$, at least).

Comment: Look at last statement. We have p=2001, a = 203 and N = 7979. How do I find X and Y ?

Comment: I don't see how that answers any of my questions.  What is a "rigorously integer number"?  Do you just mean an "integer"?  I think (well, guess really) that you are just asking "is there an algorithm for solving $x^2\equiv b\pmod n$?"  to which the answer is yes, but it is not obvious.  See the [Tonelli Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm)

Comment: To your numerical question, using quadratic reciprocity, we see that there is no solution to $x^2\equiv 2001-203\equiv 60\pmod {79}$ so there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: lulu, Tonelli Shanks refer to the modulo of an odd prime.
Delete the term "rigorously" from "rigorously integer".
I think that vvgiri gave at least a partial explanation to this problem which seems, after discussing, pretty untractable

Comment: This boils down to factoring $N$ by the well-known method of difference of squares representation of $N$ (or a multiple) - a method dating back to [Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method)

Comment: @Divinator  Exactly.  You first need to factor to modulus $n$, then solve the problem for each prime dividing $n$.  Tonelli Shanks is just the first step.

Comment: Oh ! Ok that's it

Comment: Should stress:  the comments in the posted solution, from @vvgirl, are not correct.  In your example, with $P=2145$, it is not true that $X-Y$ divides $N$.   Indeed, the congruence $(X-Y)(X+Y)\equiv 0\pmod N$ tells us that $N$ divides the product $(X-Y)(X+Y)$, not the other way round.

Comment: They do not divide N but they share with N a common factor (101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer:**

Note that $X^2 + a \equiv Y^2 + a \equiv P \mod N$

$\implies X^2 \equiv Y^2 \mod N$
$\implies (X - Y)(X + Y) \equiv 0 \mod N$

A family of the solutions can be found using the following:
Take $X-Y, X+Y$ to be divisors of $Nk$ for some integer $k$.

If $X - Y = d$ is a divisor of $N$, then you get

$$X - Y + X + Y = 2X = d + {Nk \over d}$$
$$\implies X = {d + {Nk \over d} \over 2}, k \in Z$$
$$\implies Y = {d + {Nk \over d} \over 2} - d$$

If you equate $X + Y = d$, you get the same family of solutions as above since $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ are the two divisors whose product equals $Nk$.

These are not the only solutions because there could be divisors of $Nk$ that are not divisors of $N$ (divisors of $k$).

Comment: "This means −,+ are divisors of  for some integer ."  No.  It means that $N\,|\,(X-Y)(X+Y)$.  Every non-zero integer, $c$, is a divisor of $Nk$ for some $k$. Take $k=c$ for example.

Comment: Thanks vvgiri, nice observations !